# Send local message from an Arduino to a Flutter app on Android/iOS?

Tags: android, flutter, arduino, esp8266, httpserver

I have a need to send a message from an Arduino to a Flutter app on a local WiFi network. I was thinking I could perhaps run a HTTP server on the mobile device and just make a GET/POST request from the Arduino, but I can't seem to find a http server plugin for Flutter which would run on a mobile device.

Any ideas how to accomplish this? I know I could use something like Firebase or Blynk, but it would require the devices to have Internet access, which I would want to avoid.

Comment: which Arduino?  I was using Arduino mega plus ESP8266-esp01 and use classic socket to connect a node.js server, and flutter app connect the same node.js server by socket.io

Comment: And I found that the ESP8266 is not reliable, it sometimes disconnect with unknown reason, and in order to communicate between arduino and flutter client, a Linux server with node.js is required.  Finally, I replace the arduino + esp8266, with Raspberry Pi 3b+, the sensors attached to the arduino are now attached to the Raspberry Pi directly, and I install node.js and socket.io in this raspbian to connect the flutter app.

Comment: @KennethLi I was considering socket connections, but as you say it seems like a less reliable solution than simply opening a connection and sending a HTTP request  when a message should be delivered. In my case, messages would be very few and far between (perhaps a few each day), so there's no need to keep a connection open all the time.

Comment: can you turn your mobile phone screen on 24/7?  the Android system kills the network connection of an app around 5 mins after screen is off.

Comment: @MagnusW How did you solve this? I want to use Java Springboot server between Android client and Hardware.

Comment: @Badamchi I didn't solve it. I'm still using Firebase, which requires an internet connection to work. On the other hand, it's been working really well for over a year now. I'm sending a HTTP request from the Arduino to a server, where a PHP script sends a FCM (Firebase Cloud Message) to the mobile app (which uses the Firebase Messaging plugin). If you do solve it using local messaging, I'd love to hear about it in an answer :)